# Nested block table layout breaks in Internet Explorer 10

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have nested block table.

```css
.cell_group,
.cell_group--root,
.cell_group--nested {
  display: table;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.cell_group__row {
  display: table-row;
}
.cell_group__cell,
.cell_group__edge_cell {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 1px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #f00;
}
.cell_group__edge_cell {
  padding: 5px;
}
.cell_group__wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.cell_group--nested {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="cell_group">
  <div class="cell_group__row">
    <div class="cell_group__edge_cell">test</div>
    <div class="cell_group__cell">
      <div class="cell_group--nested">
        <div class="cell_group__row">
          <div class="cell_group__edge_cell">test</div>
        </div>
        <div class="cell_group__row">
          <div class="cell_group__edge_cell">test</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell_group__cell">
      <div class="cell_group--nested">
        <div class="cell_group__row">
          <div class="cell_group__edge_cell">test</div>
        </div>
        <div class="cell_group__row">
          <div class="cell_group__edge_cell">test</div>
        </div>
        <div class="cell_group__row">
          <div class="cell_group__edge_cell">test</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Everything works fine in all major browsers... but not in IE10. Central column doesn't fill the full height of the container and leaves space. How can I make central cells to equally distribute to full height of the column?

Comment: How exactly is that broken - it renders as I would expect - 3 columns, the first with 1 row, the second with 2 rows, the third with 3

Comment: it does that in chrome too